# Logic in JMeter Script to handle padding(space)

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Need to pass 34 length value for a field in JMeter.
length of padding = 34-(len(itemcode)+1) 
need to have space for padding as per above calculation.

total 34 length for this field= ItemCode+"N"+X ,
the "N" length = 34-len(ItemCode)-1

Item code need to fetch from previous response.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by JSR223 post-processor with below code.

```
    log.info('${prod2name}');
    var s= '${prod2name}';
    var totallength=34;
    var vallength=s.length;
    var spacelength=totallength-parseInt(vallength)-1;
    var finall=s;

    for(i=1;i<=spacelength;i++){
        finall=finall+" ";  
        }
    var finall=finall+"X";
    log.info(finall.length);
    vars.put("z",finall);
```